# How many polynomials $P(x)$ of degree not exceeding 3 are there such that each coefficient is a non-negative integer less than 10, and that $P(-1)=-9$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials

> How many polynomials $P(x)$ of degree not exceeding 3 are there such that each coefficient is a non-negative integer less than 10, and that $P(-1)=-9$?

My attempt:There would be one linear polynomial i.e. $9x=0$

Edit:Let the quadratic equations be of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$ then the required condition would be $a+c-b=-9$ but minimum possible value of $a+cl-b$ is $-8$ so there would be no such quadratic equations.

Now, let the cubic polynomial be of the form $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ then we need such cubics which satisfy this condition:
$-(a+c)+b+d=9\\i.e. b+d=9+a+c$
Now $a$ can be anything between 1 and 9 while $\text{b,c and d}$ can be anything between 0 to 9.
Now, maximum value of $b+d$ would be 18. So,the above condition would reduce to $18-9=9=a+d$ with the condition that both $\text{a and b}$  are non negative integers less than 10 and $a$ can not be equal to zero. Using, combinatorics it can be easily found that number of solutions of this equation is $\binom{9}1=9$.

Second largest value of $b+d$ would be 17.Thus, giving the condition $a+c=8$ which has 8 solutions. Besides,$b+d=17$ can be written in $2$ ways. So, total number of solutions is equal to $8.2=16$.
Continuing further similarly we get,

$a+c=7=> \text{Number of solutions}=7.3=21\\ a+c=6=> \text{Number of solutions}=6.4=24\\a+c=5=> \text{Number of solutions}=5.5=25\\a+c=4=> \text{Number of solutions}=4.6=24\\a+c=3=> \text{Number of solutions}=3.7=21\\a+c=2=> \text{Number of solutions}=2.8=16\\a+c=1=> \text{Number of solutions}=1.9=9$

Adding all these should give answer. But their sum is 166 which is the wrong answer.

Correct answer: $\binom{12}3=220$

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Did you consider quadratic  and linear equations

Comment: Yes, there would be zero according to me. Let me add that to my attempt.

Comment: Given that the answer is $\binom{12}3=220$ there might be simpler ways to solve this

Comment: How did you determine minimum possible value of a+c-b

Comment: @Asher221 Yes, I have been also thinking the same

Comment: @satyamkumarjha please tell

Comment: @Lalit Tolani, all of a,b and c are possitive. To get the minimum value I will put the minimum value of a+c while the maximum value of b. As a cannot be zero (otherwise it won't remain a quadratic equation) I will get 1+0-9=-8

Comment: @Lalit Tolani, Yes. Besides, I have edited the question while working on your concerns

Comment: Ok now everything seems fine to me but still I will continue looking at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126061/discussion-between-satyam-kumar-jha-and-lalit-tolani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(b-a)+(d-c)=9$$
Imagine a line with 9 red balls and 3 green balls. Consider the following example,
[image]
The number of red balls from the start till the first green ball gives you the value for $a$.
The number of red balls from the start till the second green ball gives you the value for $b-a$.

The number of red balls from the second green ball till the third green ball gives you the value for $c$.
The number of red balls from the second green ball till the end gives you the value for $d-c$.

This has $\binom{12}3=220$ solutions

Comment: I had tried to think on the similar lines.But what  I am unable to understand is that,  we would have got the same answer for a+b+c+d=9. How did we take the minus signs in account

Comment: @satyamkumarjha $b\ge a$ and $d\ge c$ so $a,b-a,d,c-d$ are always non negative.

Comment: @satyamkumarjha Note that if $b<a$ or if $d<c$ then there are no solutions. There is also no solution if one of  $a,b,c,d\ge 10$

Comment: Took me a while to get you Thanks for the efforts